# pattern example for apache index of

Tags: apache

When reading the following documentation:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html

I see the option:

- P=pattern lists only files matching the given pattern

However, I can't find an example anywhere and can get it to work.
Does someone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its quite simple really. Let's suppose:

- Your DocumentRoot is /var/www
- You have defined Options Indexes or +Indexes for /var/www
- Your DocumentRoot has this file list: a,b,c,d,d1,d2,f,g
- You want to list files starting with d.

In this case all you have to do is request this:
http://example.com/?P=d*

The pattern to use is similar or like used since DOS, ? for a caracter * for matching lots of characters. So if you wanted to match files which third character is a "n" you would use this pattern ??n*

and it will list only files matching that pattern. Try it out.